# Menor index para múltiplos elementos

Tags: jquery

Por padrão o jQuery retorna sempre o maior index quando o seletor retorna mais de um elemento, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="error">3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="error">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>



$('li').click(function(){
    alert($('.error').parents('ul').index());  
})
```

Também tentei assim:

```
alert($('.error')[0].parents('ul').index());
```

No entanto, esta instrução devolve:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: O que você quer retornar?

Comment: O menor valor de index

Comment: Tentou $('.error').closest('ul').index()); ? Mas pelo que vi, o que você pega o index(), são das li, no seu caso seria $(this).index()...

Comment: ou $('.error').closest('ul').find('li:first').index(); OBS: Não testei

Comment: Não sei se é isso que vc quer, mas tente: `$('.error').eq(0).parent().index()`

Comment: Você resolveu o problema? Ainda não entendi bem o que você quer.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você deseja obter o index do item com a classe `error` da `<ul>` atual você deve utilizar `this`:

```
$(this).parent().find('.error').index()
```

Para obter o index do primeiro item com a classe `error` em relação a `<ul>` pai:

```
$('.error:eq(0)').index()
```

Note que a função `.index()` sem argumentos retorna a posição do item atual em relação aos elementos adjacentes

Ainda, se você precisa do index do primeiro item com a classe `error` em relação à todos os `<li>` utilize:

```
$('li').index($('.error'))
```